# OAuth Unauthorized Client Error

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-mirror-api, google-glass

Working on my Google Glassware and everything seemed to be going fine. I tried loading it up the other day after a while of not working on it and had an OAuth error. I tried refreshing the key and even starting a new project. The Error I got has atleast changed I am now getting -
An error occurred: Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "unauthorized_client" }'

The code is pretty much completely based off of the PHP Quick Start. This happens when I try and authorize the app with my account. I know my information is correct for the config.php file. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oauth is handled the same way across most Google APIs. There are many possible causes of this. My guess is that your refresh token somehow became invalid, so you cannot use it to get new access tokens. Have you tried looking at these answers? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871982/unable-to-refresh-access-token-response-is-unauthorized-client http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792326/how-do-i-refresh-my-google-oauth2-access-token-using-my-refresh-token http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878605/authorize-google-calendar-api-works-on-personal-account-but-not-on-google-domain

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mirror API unauthorized\_client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226596/mirror-api-unauthorized-client)

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case , it is possible that Authorization server has not allowed to access Authorization grant type

`{error: 'unauthorized client'}` may be related to Authorization server settings
`Grant_types` it has allowed.

Reference: http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12.html#token-errors